# object-oriented draughts implementation using collections of allowed moves and setwise operations

Tags: java, oop, collections

At my university I was given a task of implementing draughts game in a literate, object-oriented way following mvc design pattern. I was told that:

- each of two game pieces should form a separate class that has separate fields for attack and non-capturing move in a form of collection;
- checking the validity of a given move should be performed in a setwise manner.

I have no idea hot to do this, that is:

1. how to implement moves in the above defined way, i.e. in a form of collection
2. what sort of setwise operations should I use.
3. What sort of sets should I have, the procedural approach feels much more natural to me.

I'd be thankful for any suggestions on that or links discussing such implementations.

Some problems I find here. First of all, I guess model is given a mere pair of field indexes from a client view. So there is no initial information as to the nature of the move, i.e. whether it is a capturing on non-capturing move. In case of a king piece is not immediately given. Secondly, I guess the piece class should contain some sort of a vector, but how to account for men's limitation of moving only forward or either king's unlimited length of a move or requirement in some draught's rules that king should step one field after the captured piece?

Additional requirements were that implementation should be oriented towards legal directions of a game (diagonals) not around an array and that it should be elastic enough to fit different regional variations of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some insight on what you might want to try.  Start with the view, if you can not create the "Checkers" board there is little use in going on.

Step 1: create the "view" the visual of the board with what ever gui programming language you wish.

Step 2: create the basic model, what the pieces are, ie, pawn or queen are the only two allowable pieces, set up icons for each single chip of course for pawn 2 stack for queen.

Step 3: setup the controller: one accept mouse clicks on the view board that captures whether it is selecting a position on the board that has a piece, and then realizes it is a piece and then outlines the possible moves of the piece.  The controller should also tell the view board to update where the icon of the piece is on the board including when the game starts all the locations of the starting pieces which is stored in some collection in the model.

I would create an instance of the class for the pieces for each piece on the board easily done using a loop to create the pieces.  Once you have those steps done you should be able to easily modify it to know when it is a capture move, an upgrade move(when a pawn reaches the other end of the board) illegal and legal moves.